# How to access DOL's ETA data?

Tags: usa, labor

Is there a way to access DOL's ETA data through the DOL's API? I am particularly interested in H1B/LCA and PERM data.

Comment: This is a world wide site. The least you should do is add a country tag to your question, but maybe explaining this acronym soup would be nice to the readers.

Comment: @JanDoggen we've been through this before. its not the posters fault/problem, i'm not arguing with you, but have to point out again, that new users are just following what they've been told to do. this is something to bring up in meta, or add on to the post i created there. maybe if more people comment the admins will actually respond.

Comment: @albert I assume you mean this question: http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/351/editing-a-tags-name-wondering-about-us-gov-involvement-just-the-usual? Aha, I did not know this was going on. Frankly, it's ridiculous. They are not even told anything. See the answer I posted there.

Comment: apologies Jan, i've had discussions with a few people here on this, for some reason thought one had been with you. essentially, someone is going around in us gov telling agencies to send their questions here. there is no feedback loop, no coordination, and no planning, from what i can tell. its really annoying and even more so because the people doing it (i only assume are the admins here) do not respond in meta, while i'm assuming still doing nothing about it. it super annoyed me to see "labor" associated with a us fed agency. as if it doesn't happen globally, or here locally....

Answer (score 2):

We currently don't have that data available through the API.  I will reach out to my ETA (Employment and Training Administration, US Department of Labor) colleagues with your request to have it available through the API.

Comment: Mike are you involved with DOL? Please visit the link in my comment under the question and read my answer there. Thanks.

Comment: even this answer is flawed. "we"...how is anyone supposed to know who we is. and i'm not being critical of mike, i'm pointing out the lack of coordination/communication behind this. pretty sure i've commented/edited over 10+ government officials, who are being told to come here to comment/answer, but had zero/little training prior.

Comment: @ Mike Pulsifer: Are there any updates on the public availability of this API?